# Migrating Contents to Ektron

Tags: ektron, vignette

I am working in Ektron 8.6.

I need to migrate contents from Vignette CMS to Ektron.Is there is any option in ekron to automate the content migration process rather than doing it manually(creation of contents by fetching the HTML from other CMS)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the Ektron API to add content. You will have to write that code yourself. The folders you use to organize your content in Ektron will be different from anyone else's. Also the way content is organized in Vignette is unique to your site so the import code has to be custom.

I have found that if you have fewer than 400 pieces of content it is easier to do it manually.